# How to echo data from mysql current session in php?

Tags: php, mysql, session

Before I start I must say I'm a huge noob to php. I'm following a tutorial online on how to make a login/registration php page with MySQL: https://daveismyname.blog/login-and-registration-system-with-php

I added my own SQL column named 'investment' as int(11).

I am able to echo SESSION username, but not session investment.

The default value of the investment column is '0' not sure if this matters, but stating it anyway.

When the echo is called the spot where the amount is supposed to be is just empty.

**index.php(echo of investment):**

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle waves-effect waves-button waves-classic fa fa-usd" data-toggle="dropdown"> Invested Amount: $
  <?php echo $_SESSION['investment'];?>
  <i class="fa fa-angle-down">
  </i>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu title-caret dropdown-lg" role="menu">
  <li class="drop-all">
    <a href="#" class="text-center">Portfolio
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="drop-all">
    <a href="#" class="text-center">Invest
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle waves-effect waves-button waves-classic" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="user-name">
      <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['username'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>
      <i class="fa fa-angle-down">
      </i>
    </span>
  </a>
```

**Code handling SESSION:**

```
<?php
include('password.php');
class User extends Password{
    private $_db;
    function __construct($db){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_db = $db;
    }
    private function get_user_hash($username){
        try {
            $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT password, username, memberID, investment,email FROM members WHERE username = :username AND active="Yes" ');
            $stmt->execute(array('username' => $username));
            return $stmt->fetch();
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
        }
    }
    public function isValidUsername($username){
        if (strlen($username) < 3) return false;
        if (strlen($username) > 17) return false;
        if (!ctype_alnum($username)) return false;
        return true;
    }
    public function login($username,$password){
        if (!$this->isValidUsername($username)) return false;
        if (strlen($password) < 3) return false;
        $row = $this->get_user_hash($username);
        if($this->password_verify($password,$row['password']) == 1){
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
            $_SESSION['memberID'] = $row['memberID'];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
            $_SESSION['investment'] = $row['investment'];
            return true;
        }
    }
    public function logout(){
        session_destroy();
    }
    public function is_logged_in(){
        if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true){
            return true;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Where is `session_start()`, Is it in `password.php` ?

Comment: Have you inserted any data in `investment` column? Or trying printing `print_r($_SESSION)` variable if you are getting that.

Comment: @DaniyalNasir It's stored inside the config.php file which is called in this order: index.php > config.php > user.php(handles session)

Comment: @NitinKawane Yes, there is data in the column.

Comment: if `session_Start()` is in password.php then put some static value in investment column. and then do `print_r($_SESSION)`. maybe you are not getting the investment value in session

Comment: @SyedAmirBukhari Hmm, only returns ['loggedin'], ['username'], ['memberID']

Comment: @SyedAmirBukhari How would I fix that?

Comment: @WeDaBeast i think your investment variable `$row['investment']` is not getting the data. please double check the DB if it has something. for debugging prospective you have to `print_r($row)` first and check either its coming or not.